# Discord bot setRole command works only randomly

Tags: node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I've quite recently made a bot with a simple algorithm. The bot is supposed to welcome you on a certain channel, then you must tell him your name level (on a certain game) and your team (team1 team2 or team3). When you do that he is supposed to name you after your nickname and level and set your discord role after your team and lastly after he does that he is asking you for a screenshot of your profile on pm and he sends the screenshot on another channel (this is not the important part).

The naming part and the screenshot function is working just fine and as intended, for some Unknown reason though, the setRole function works seemingly randomly. It sometimes gives the correct role to a member, it sometimes does not. Here is my algorithm:

```
if (message.channel.id == welcomeid){
  var words = message.content.split(' ');
  var name = words[0];
  var number = words[1];
  var team = words[2];
  if (typeof words[0] === "undefined" || typeof words[1] === "undefined" || typeof words[2] === "undefined"){
    message.reply("error checker")
    return;
  }
  team = team.toLowerCase();

    if (name.includes('team1') == 1 || name.includes('team2') == 1 || name.includes('team3') == 1 || name.includes('team4') == 1   ){
      message.reply("Another error");
      return;
    }
    else if (name.length < 3){
      message.reply("error for name length");
      return;
    }
    else if (isNaN(number)){
      message.reply("error for checking if level is a number");
      return;
    }
    else if (number > 40 || number < 1 ) {
      message.reply("error for checking if level is above one and below 40");
      return;
    }
    else {
      if (team.includes("team1")){ //those 4 ifs are the problematic part
        message.member.setNickname(name+" | "+number)
        .then(console.log)
        .catch(console.error);
      message.member.addRole(team1id)
        .then(console.log)
        .catch(console.error);
      screenShot();
    }
    else if (team.includes("team2")){
      message.member.setNickname(name+" | "+number)
      .then(console.log)
      .catch(console.error);
      message.member.addRole(team2id)
       .then(console.log)
       .catch(console.error);
      screenShot();
    }
    else if (team.includes("team3")){
      message.member.setNickname(name+" | "+number)
      .then(console.log)
      .catch(console.error);
      message.member.addRole(team3id)
        .then(console.log)
        .catch(console.error);
      screenShot();
    }
    else if (team.includes("team4")){
      message.member.setNickname(name+" | "+number)
      .then(console.log)
      .catch(console.error);
      message.member.addRole(team4id)
        .then(console.log)
        .catch(console.error);
      screenShot();
    }
    else {
      message.reply("team error");
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

Of course I Don't need the bot to give the roles whenever it feels like it and I can't see any part of the code which contradicts with the "addrole" function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no visible errors in your code, the only thing I would get rid of is not unnecessary else blocks. Because if any of the parameters is entered incorrectly, you leave the function with `return`. Check if the role of your bot is higher than the roles of all participants. If not, he will not be able to change the nickname or give out this role.

```
  if (message.channel.id == welcomeid){
    var words = message.content.split(' ');
    var name = words[0];
    var number = words[1];
    var team = words[2];
    if (typeof words[0] === "undefined" || typeof words[1] === "undefined" || typeof words[2] === "undefined"){
        return message.reply("error checker")
    }

    team = team.toLowerCase();

    if (name.includes('team1') == 1 || name.includes('team2') == 1 || name.includes('team3') == 1 || name.includes('team4') == 1   ){
      message.reply("Another error");
      return;
    } else if (name.length < 3){
      message.reply("error for name length");
      return;
    } else if (isNaN(number)){
      message.reply("error for checking if level is a number");
      return;
    } else if (number > 40 || number < 1 ) {
      message.reply("error for checking if level is above one and below 40");
      return;
    }

  if (team.includes("team1")){
        message.member.setNickname(name+" | "+number)
        .then(console.log)
        .catch(console.error);
      message.member.addRole(team1id)
        .then(console.log)
        .catch(console.error);
      screenShot();
    } else if (team.includes("team2")){
      message.member.setNickname(name+" | "+number)
          .then(console.log)
          .catch(console.error);
      message.member.addRole(team2id)
       .then(console.log)
       .catch(console.error);
      screenShot();
    } else if (team.includes("team3")){
      message.member.setNickname(name+" | "+number)
      .then(console.log)
      .catch(console.error);
      message.member.addRole(team3id)
        .then(console.log)
        .catch(console.error);
      screenShot();
    } else if (team.includes("team4")){
      message.member.setNickname(name+" | "+number)
      .then(console.log)
      .catch(console.error);
      message.member.addRole(team4id)
        .then(console.log)
        .catch(console.error);
      screenShot();
    } else {
      message.reply("team error");
      return;
    }
}
```

Comment: The bot has a specific rank which is indeed higher above all other member ranks, so that should not be the case I guess, otherwise it would not give rank/nicknames at all. I will delete the "else" blocks then, just in case and I will let you know if the problem persists. Thanks.

Comment: Well, I made several tests and it didn't fail to give me a role not even once, that's a good sign as it should have failed more than once by now. I will only note that it once didn't give a nickname to the user but I can consider it was a visual bug, I think it happened once in the past. I can't really see how the "else" statements have any effect in all this but hey! As long as it works... XD